# how hdfs and hive are related?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have psudeo distributed hadoop environment and using sqoop and hive for data importing and analysis.

I used sqoop to import data from mysql to hive and it worked, i got data in my hive location which is `/user/hive/warehouse/` and i can able to see the data in hive table.

my doubts are :

1. will the data stored in hadoop when i import from mysql to hive(build on top of hadoop)?
2. why it is creating `/user/hive/warehouse` in my hdfs?
3. how hive would work on top of data?
4. if i update data in mysql , i can use sqoop incremental import to update the same in hdfs but if i directly use hive import it will reflect in hive table but not not in hdfs, is my understanding correct?

I am confuse while performing data ingestion using sqoop and hdfs concept

Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Answers

1- Data is stored in HDFS only.

2- Property "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" at hive-default.xml value tells where data will be stored default value is "/user/hive/warehouse"

3- User Query are converted on MapReduse job [more detail](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Design)

4- You can use SQOOP for incremental data load and all data will be stored on HDFS and if you have created table on the it will reflect.

Comment: let's say if i update record in mysql and use incremental import to sqoop

Comment: 1203 | adithyan | be      |   30000 | AC   |
| 1204 | prasanth |  phpdev |   30000 | AC   |
| 1205 | adithyan | b.tech  | 5000000 | IT

Comment: kapil has been updated to adithyan in first row and 7874575 has been updated to 1205 in mysql

Comment: how do i update the same record in hive table which currently looks like below

Comment: 1203 kalil   phpdev 30000 AC
1204 prasanth  phpdev 30000 AC
7894561230245879546 adithyan b.tech 5000000 IT

Comment: i didn't created the table with any timestamp becuase my column has only bigint and varchar type data's, in this case how do i update the record from mysql to hive ?

Comment: Hi Please go throw it will give all answers. https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.0/bk_dataintegration/content/incrementally-updating-hive-table-with-sqoop-and-ext-table.html

Comment: following sqoop command says for updating the data from MySQL to hive   sqoop import --connect jdbc:teradata://{host name}/Database=retail 
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager 
--username dbc --password dbc --table SOURCE_TBL --target-dir /user/hive/incremental_table -m 1 
--check-column modified_date --incremental lastmodified --last-value {last_import_date}\

Comment: my question is let's say i'm updating from web application to database I may not be knowing the previous/last_import_value, in this case how do I give the value for  'last-value' in sqoop command above?

Comment: i would have update 1000's of records in MySQL from web application, how do i keep the update record in existing table at hive?

Comment: For these kind of use case schedule the Sqoop in oozie to keep track at regular intervals !!

Comment: ok, for simple record if i want to update in hive without using oozie, is it possible to update without knowing the last-import-value using sqoop?

Comment: Frist of all Hive supports only partial ACID transactions. As as a workaround - if it is possible to add a new column named last update value as datetime on your mastertable in MY SQL, It will be more easier to identify the last modified record . Using that you can able to update it using sqoop itself.